# Remove UITableView header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've been playing around with this problem for almost a day now, and I have no idea what else I can do.

I have a UITableView embedded in a UIScrollView. The UITableView the its tableHeaderView, which is empty and I want to get rid of.

I tried:

- `tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;`
- `tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];`
- **The style is plain not grouped.**
- Added a blank view. (Some people suggested this, as it makes the tableview not the first in the hierachy. Actually this one does work, if the tableview isn't embedded in the scrollview.)

Comment: Can you show us the code, the Interface Builder screenshot, or the iPhone screenshot?

Comment: *screenshot please...* **I have a UITableView embedded in a UIScrollView**... ***NEVER EVER DO THIS...*** *could you give more details on what you are trying to do? might we will help you out with a better and proper way*

Comment: vote to close for not adding requested information.

Comment: Along with the UITableview I have other elements in the UIScrollview, that's why I don't have other options.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code mutating the `tableHeaderView` property in `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableHeaderView.endUpdates()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0.01)];
```

Make the **height** of the tableHeaderView **MORE THAN** 0.

Answer (score -1):

Find the following methods in your code and remove them:

```
– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:
```

Comment: OP said that the table style is plain, not grouped, so none of these should be being called.

Comment: tableHeaderView != section headerView